# Why does lubridate::ymd_hms not work for a very specific date-time?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the date-time `2019-03-10 02:43:00`  in `POSIXct` format. Note the following behavior:

```
lubridate::ymd_hms("2019-03-10 02:43:00",  tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
[1] NA
Warning message:
 1 failed to parse.

lubridate::ymd_hms("2019-03-10 01:59:00",  tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2019-03-10 01:59:00 PST"

lubridate::ymd_hms("2019-03-10 03:00:00",  tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2019-03-10 03:00:00 PDT"
```

Any time value between 02:00 - 02:59 for this date gives ```NA``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that in the US/Pacific time zone on 2019-03-10 changed to daylight savings at 02:00, making any time on this day between 02:00 - 02:59 ambiguous.

Edit: As noted by Rui in the comments, the 2nd Sunday in March is the official switch to [daylight savings in the US.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone#Daylight_time)

I am posting in the hope that others find this useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: You could greatly improve the question by adding a link to this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone#Daylight_time) entry on Pacific daylight savings. And `format(as.Date("2019-03-10"), "%w")` returns `0`, meaning it's a Sunday. And as day 10 of the month it's the *2nd* Sunday of March.